# PHP Glob: How to use multiple flags with glob function?

Tags: php, glob

I want to use both `GLOB_NOSORT` and `GLOB_BRACE` with `glob()` function, is that possible?

The reason is I don't want any sorting by glob() function, my current code looks like this:

```
$filetypes = '{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc,*.docx,*.zip,*.jpeg,*.jpg,*.gif,*.ping,*.zip,*.rar}';
//assign $files to results of glob()
$files = glob($structure.$filetypes, GLOB_BRACE);

usort($files, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));

print_r($files);
```

Above code will not sort the files according to `filemtime()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$files = glob($structure.$filetypes, GLOB_NOSORT | GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Also, resist the urge to separate each filetype with a comma and space.  Just use a comma.