# php glob - how to get folders properly sorted

Tags: php, glob

I'm on localhost, win 7, xampp

Need to create divs from all (and only) folders inside `../HOME`

Originally, folders are sorted by name.

```
$arr = glob('../HOME/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$cnt = '';
foreach($arr as $el){
    $cnt .= "<div class = 'folder rfolder'>" . basename($el) . "</div>\n";
}
echo $cnt;
```

Result - folders are sorted by the time created.

Tried - `$arr = glob('../HOME/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR, GLOB_NOSORT)` and getting error - `only two arguments allowed`.

How to get folders sorted originally - as inside source folder?

Comment: let me tell one thing, you are have nested folder tree under home, and you want all the folder and sub-folder name, is it true ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351095/php-glob-how-to-use-multiple-flags-with-glob-function

Comment: @iamawesome, no, need just folders inside `../HOME`, without nested folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with

```
    $arr = glob('../HOME/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT)
```

also, you can sort `$arr` using php `usort` function easily, do what suits you best

Answer (score 2):

They are flags that can be combined using a `bitwise OR`

```
$arr = glob('../HOME/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT)
```